# Variable passed in with each method being treated as attribute for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm writing a rspec test where I loop through various attributes of a model to test for presence. However, whenever I insert the variable `attr` into the looped through code, it reads attr as an attribute itself and not a variable. How do I fix this? I know this can be done.

```
describe "testing the presence" do

  ["title", "url", "post_id"].each do |attr|

    it "tests presence for #{attr}" do
    #attr being recognized as actual model attribute
    link = Link.new(attr: "")
    link.should be_invalid
    link.errors.should_not be_nil

    end

  end

end
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand, but I'm not convinced using a string variable with a colon after it is going to do what you think it is. Maybe try old-map syntax, `attr => ""`, otherwise it's going to convert `attr` to the string `"attr"` as the key. Or convert it to a symbol if that's what you need.

Comment: Do what Dave says.  Or, consider using https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers

Comment: Thanks Dave. It works now using the old-map syntax. Post it as an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify it to use old syntax of symb=>value such as

```
describe "testing the presence" do

  ["title", "url", "post_id"].each do |attr|

    it "tests presence for #{attr}" do
    #attr being recognized as actual model attribute
    **link = Link.new(attr.to_sym => "")**
    link.should be_invalid
    link.errors.should_not be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

also you might just want to send a method to it such as

```
link = Link.new
link.send attr.to_sym, ""
```

Comment: Thanks Yuriy for the Other suggestions. If Dave ends up not answering the question I'll give you credit.

Comment: i would also checkout shoulda matchers that Phillip mentioned. Thats the approach i personally tend to use the most